# ORA-01034: Oracle not available, background process 'QMNC' did not start

Tags: oracle, ora-01034

I am trying to create to connect with oracle sqlplus. It gives error :

```
ORA-01034: Oracle not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

I checked the alert_geis.log and got the error(geis is the SID_NAME):

```
    Trace file e:\program\oracle\diag\rdbms\geis\geis\trace\geis_ora_6176.trc
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
Windows NT Version V6.1 Service Pack 1 
CPU                 : 8 - type 8664, 4 Physical Cores
Process Affinity    : 0x0x0000000000000000
Memory (Avail/Total): Ph:4022M/8122M, Ph+PgF:8131M/16243M 
Instance name: geis
Redo thread mounted by this instance: 1
Oracle process number: 19
Windows thread id: 6176, image: ORACLE.EXE (SHAD)


*** 2014-05-09 18:53:19.653
*** SESSION ID:(22.3) 2014-05-09 18:53:19.653
*** CLIENT ID:() 2014-05-09 18:53:19.653
*** SERVICE NAME:(SYS$USERS) 2014-05-09 18:53:19.653
*** MODULE NAME:(oradim.exe) 2014-05-09 18:53:19.653
*** ACTION NAME:() 2014-05-09 18:53:19.653

kwqmnich: current time:: 10: 53: 19: 0
kwqmnich: instance no 0 repartition flag 1 
kwqmnich: initialized job cache structure 
**ORA-00020: No more process state objects available
ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced
ORA-00450: background process 'QMNC' did not start
ORA-00444: background process "QMNC" failed while starting
ORA-00020: maximum number of processes () exceeded**

*** 2014-05-09 18:53:20.011
USER (ospid: 6176): terminating the instance due to error 450
```

I google it, but there was little helpful information about 'QMNC'. While I have checked the logs carefully, couldn't find the reasons of error.
I appreciate someone whom will fix it.
Thanks advance.

Comment: I think the error of importance is: ORA-00020: maximum number of processes () exceeded**.

Comment: I have rebooted my computer. It has error still. If the error is caused by too many processes, it will be OK by restart.